# height() returns different values in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
</ul>
```

```
var h = $('li').height();
console.log(h);
```

In Firefox it says 80 but in Chrome it says 60.

What's the issue?

Comment: Everythings fine for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is different default line-height and padding in different browsers. Padding is always counted as a part of the object. Just define padding and line-height, etc.

Comment: I managed to get the same result in this particular example by setting ul padding to 0, but in the CSS for my plugin I already had that, and it still won't work there. Anyway, the problem seems to be some wayward padding. Anyway, isn't height() supposed to ignore padding?

Comment: @dzumla011 height includes padding. The difference b/w margin and padding is that margin is an external part of an object and padding is internal. Look at this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp